# What is the best way to get a `*const c_char` from a const array via FFI?

Tags: rust, ffi

I am trying to interface with a C API in Rust. They define a couple of string constants with macros:

```c
#define kOfxImageEffectPluginApi "OfxImageEffectPluginAPI"
```

and a struct with a `const char *pluginApi;` where that constant is supposed to be used:

```c
typedef struct OfxPlugin {
  const char *pluginApi;
  // Other fields...
} OfxPlugin;
```

[Bindgen (servo)](https://github.com/servo/rust-bindgen) creates the following Rust equivalent:

```rust
pub const kOfxImageEffectPluginApi: &'static [u8; 24usize] = b"OfxImageEffectPluginAPI\x00";
```

```rust
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug, Copy)]
pub struct OfxPlugin {
    pub pluginApi: *const ::std::os::raw::c_char,
    // other fields...
}
```

What is the best way to get a `*const c_char` from that const array? I tried both `as_ptr` and a cast, but the types don't match because the array is `u8` and `c_char` is `i8`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from a minimal example and work our way through:

```
const K: &'static [u8; 24usize] = b"OfxImageEffectPluginAPI\x00";

#[derive(Debug)]
struct OfxPlugin {
    plugin_api: *const ::std::os::raw::c_char,
    // other fields...
}

fn main() {
    let p = OfxPlugin { plugin_api: K };
    println!("{:?}", p);
}
```

The first thing to do is to get a pointer from the array; this is indeed `as_ptr()`.

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> <anon>:10:41
   |
10 |         let p = OfxPlugin { plugin_api: K.as_ptr() };
   |                                         ^^^^^^^^^^ expected i8, found u8

error: aborting due to previous error
```

The types mismatch, so we need to cast from one pointer type to another. This is achieved with `as`:

```
fn main() {
    let p = OfxPlugin { plugin_api: K.as_ptr() as *const _ };
    println!("{:?}", p);
}
```

We *could* be explicit about the kind of pointer we want; but it's simpler here to let the compiler manage it.

Comment: Thanks! I never thought about using both at the same time. A follow up question, why doesn't it work when you have only `as *const _`?

Comment: @MathieuDavid: `as` can only perform a very limited number of conversions, and array to pointer is not one of them. I wonder if there's a limit somewhere of what it can do...

Comment: I see. I tried chaining two casts `as *const _ as *const _` and that works. It seems strange to require two explicit casts instead of one.

Comment: @MathieuDavid: Ah, so the array to pointer conversion does work and it's just that `as` only converts one thing at a time. I thing I prefer it that way rather, it makes it more obvious what conversions are taking place.

Comment: Yes, `as_ptr` is definitely more elegant. I just tried the double cast because I wanted to make a static instance of `OfxPlugin` and `as_ptr` can't be used in that scenario.